# Subclass inside the subclass C#

Tags: c#

I am having trouble accessing the subclass inside the subclass. Should I remove the `employee` class instead or is there a way to call the `faculty` class into an object. I added a subclass to inherit the variables inside the superclass `person`, and I needed to add a subclass INSIDE the subclass but I can't seem to access the `public class faculty : employee` subclass. I don't know if this makes sense, sorry.

```
    public class person
{
    public String name{get; set;}
    public String address{get; set;}
    public String gender{get; set;}
    public int phone{get; set;}
    public string email{get; set;}
    public int birthDate{get; set;}
    public String slg{get; set;}
    public string course{get; set;}
    public string designation{get; set;}
    public int salary{get; set;}
    public String CollegeDepartment{get; set;}
    public String SubjectLoad{get; set;}
    public String ServiceDepartment{get; set;}
}
public class student : person
{
    public student(String studentName)
    {
        name = studentName;
    }
}
public class employee : person
{
    public class faculty : employee
    {
        public faculty(String facultyName)
        {
            name = facultyName;
        }
    }
    public class staff : employee
    {
        public staff (String staffName)
        {
            name = staffName;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't access the faculty subclass using

```
    public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
                
        faculty mem = new faculty("Ray");
    }
}
```

So basically, the problem is I can't access a subclass inside a subclass. A help will be appreciated

Comment: What if you just changed it so `faculty` and `staff` still inherited from `employee` but were _not inner classes_ of `employee`?

Comment: from your code, i can not reproduce your problem. could you please be more specific, and tell us any error messages you are getting, and/or how the code is behaving & how that differs from how it should? and how does the `person`-class come into play?

Comment: The `person` contains the declared variable

Comment: sorry, but even with your edit i cannot reproduce _any_ error. _please add more details about the problem you are having_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to change this...

```
faculty mem = new faculty("Ray");
```

...to this...

```
employee.faculty mem = new employee.faculty("Ray");
```

Comment: Ok,  that is the exact answer I was looking for. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for marking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that you have a reference to your `employee` class to wherever you're trying to instantiate this `faculty`.

For example, I created a basic console application with the classes you showed. I could not create a `faculty` object until I had `using ConsoleApp1.Program.person.employee` (where the class was stored).

```
using System;
using static ConsoleApp1.Program.person.employee;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            faculty bob = new faculty("wow");
        }

        public class person
        {
            public class employee : person
            {
                public class faculty : employee
                {
                    string Name { get; set; }
                    public faculty(String facultyName)
                    {
                        Name = facultyName;
                    }
                }
                public class staff : employee
                {
                    string Name { get; set; }
                    public staff(String staffName)
                    {
                        Name = staffName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please do not post code and other _text-based_ information as screenshot. provide it as formatted **text** instead.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann, thank you for the note. I opted for a screenshot to illustrate that the code itself was no issue, but I can see how this may be unhelpful.

Comment: Oh ok, I think that might work. Thank you sir.